# How can I get the top 20 city names with Google Analytics?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am working with Google Analytics and want to display the top 20 cities in my report. This code  gets visits for top 20 cities but I don't know how to get the city name according to visit.

```
$geographicPages = $ga->getReport(
    array('dimensions'=>urlencode('ga:city'),
        'metrics'=>urlencode('ga:visits'),
        'max-results' => 20,  
        'sort'=>'-ga:visits',
        'filters'=>'ga:city!%3DSurat'
    )
);
```

Comment: From the FAQ - "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.



This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (And if you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)"

Comment: No problem. My goal is certainly not to be rude, just to give you a tip which may increase your chances of getting the help that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I got Answer of this question
Code is

```
$geographicPages = $ga->getReport(
        array('dimensions'=>urlencode('ga:city'),
            'metrics'=>urlencode('ga:visits'),
            'max-results' => 20,  
            'sort'=>'-ga:visits',
            'filters'=>'ga:city!%3DSurat'
            )
        );

if(count($geographicPages)>0)
{
     foreach($geographicPages as $cityname=>$curGeoPage)
     {
          echo $cityname." : ".$curGeoPage['ga:visits'];
     }
}
```